# data.table applying function by row in R

Tags: r

I have a function that takes arguments and I want to apply it over each row in a data.table.

My data looks like follows:

```
Row    Temp   Humidity  Elevation
1       10      0.5       1000
2       25      1.5       2000
3       28      2.0       1500
```

and I have a function

```
myfunc <- function(x, n_features=3){
# Here x represents each row of a data table.
# Feature names are important for me as my actual function is operating on feature names

return(x[,Temp]+x[,Humidity]+(x[,Elevation]*(n_features)))

}
```

What I want my output to look like is

```
Row    Temp   Humidity  Elevation   myfuncout
1       10      0.5       1000      3010.5
2       25      1.5       2000      6026.5
3       28      2.0       1500      4530
```

I have tried `df[, myfuncout := myfunc(x, n_features=3), by=.I]` but this didnt work.
Also, not sure if I have to use `.SD` here to make this work...
Any inputs here on how I can achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a `data.table`, we can use

```
myfunc <- function(dt,  n_features = 3) {  
     dt[, out := (Temp + Humidity) + (Elevation * n_features)]  
     dt
}         

myfunc(df, 3)
```

-output

```
df
#   Row Temp Humidity Elevation    out
#1:   1   10      0.5      1000 3010.5
#2:   2   25      1.5      2000 6026.5
#3:   3   28      2.0      1500 4530.0
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks much better than what I was trying! One followup: If I have the column names stored in a variable (eg: ````colname=c('Temp','Humidity','Elevation')````) how can I reference that? I tried ````..colname```` but without sucess.

Comment: @FlyingPickle if you want to pass as a string.  why not subset the columns with `.SDcols` or `.SD[[colname[1]]]`